# Handling SIGINT (ctrl+c) in script but not interpreter?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, ipython, interpreter

I'm working on a project that spins off several long-running workers as processes. Child workers catch SIGINT and clean up after themselves - based on my research, this is considered a best practice, and works as expected when terminating scripts.

I am actively developing this project, which means that I am regularly testing changes in the interpreter. When I'm working in an interpreter, I often hit CTRL+C to clear currently written text and get a fresh prompt. Unfortunately, if I do this while a subprocess is running, SIGINT is sent to that worker, causing it to terminate.

Is there a solution to this problem other than "never hit CTRL+C in your interpreter"?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set a variable (e.g. environment variable, commandline option) when debugging.